# Is it better to open/close a file every time vs keeping it open until the process is finished?

Tags: python, file-io

I have a text file that is about 50 GB in size, and I am checking the first few characters of each line and writing those to other files specified for that beginning text.

For example, my input contains:

```
cow_ilovecow
dog_whreismydog
cat_thatcatshouldgotoreddit
dog_gotitfromshelter
...............
```

I want to process them in cow, dog, cat, etc. (about 200) categories,

```
if writeflag==1:
    writefile1=open(writefile,"a") #writefile is somedir/dog.txt....
    writefile1.write(remline+"\n")
    #writefile1.close()
```

What is the best way, should I close the file? Otherwise, if I keep it open, is `writefile1=open(writefile,"a")` doing the right thing?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You should definitely try to open/close the file as little as possible

Because even comparing with file read/write, file open/close is far more expensive

Consider two code blocks:

```
f=open('test1.txt', 'w')
for i in range(1000):
    f.write('\n')
f.close()
```

and

```
for i in range(1000):
    f=open('test2.txt', 'a')
    f.write('\n')
    f.close()
```

The first one takes **0.025s** while the second one takes **0.309s**

Comment: Great, should have tested, now this makes much more sense to make very few open/close statements

Comment: Extra points for showing performance results!

Answer (score 6):

Use the `with` statement, it automatically closes the files for you, do all the operations inside the `with` block, so it'll keep the files open for you and will close the files once you're out of the `with` block.

```
with open(inputfile)as f1, open('dog.txt','a') as f2,open('cat.txt') as f3:
   #do something here
```

**EDIT:**
If you know all the possible filenames to be used before the compilation of your code then using `with` is a better option and if you don't then you should use your approach but instead of closing the file you can `flush` the data to the file using `writefile1.flush()`

Comment: The `with` statement might get a bit clunky if he's opening a new file for each prefix in the input, and it's unclear if all of the possible prefixes are known at compile time.

Comment: @Wooble good point! using `with` means he needs to know all the file names before runtime, but if he knows the all the file names then in such case `with` is an better option.

Comment: Also, with 200 categories, a dict of files rather than 200 variables is probably the best solution.

Comment: @Ashwini, thanks, as other commented pointed out I don't Know the prefix of all.

Comment: What about the read-only scenario?

Answer (score 4):

Keep it open the whole time! Otherwise you tell the system that you are done writing all the time and it might decide to flush it onto the disk instead of buffering it. And for obvious reasons *n* disk writes are much more expensive than *1* disk write.

If you want to append to the file and not overwrite it then yes, `a` is the correct mode.

Answer (score 0):

IO operations consume too much time. Open and close the file, also.

It's much faster if you open both files(the input and the output), use a memory buffer with, let's say, 10MB size for your text processing and then write this to the output file. For example:

```
file = {} # just initializing dicts
filename = {}
with open(file) as f:
    file['dog'] = None
    buffer = ''
    ...
    #maybe there is a loop here
    if writeflag:
        if file['dog'] == None:
            file['dog'] = open(filename['dog'], 'a')
        buffer += remline + '\n'
    if len(buffer) > 1024*1000*10: # 10MB of text
       files['dog'].write(buffer)
       buffer = ''

for v in files.values():
    v.close()
```

Comment: I might go by this way, but I guess It should be different buffer for each prefix and so, writing to all files after processing certain lines in original files may be better option right?

Comment: -1, that's nothing you should do in your application code. Operating systems are smart enough to buffer read/write operations on their own if you let them (i.e. don't close/reopen the file after every operation). Not to mention that using a string for the buffer is pretty expensive compared to a list.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I just made a simple benchmark and it turned out that using a buffer with string was 13% faster than using io directly, and 5% faster than using buffer with list. In fact, string operations in Python are really optimized. You can check the code here: http://paste.kde.org/513206/

Comment: @Ananta Sure. This was just an example to show you how you can implement the buffer using a string and using files your files objects as a dictionary. But I'm sure that just a guide for you, i.e., you will need to write your own version.

Comment: @Felipe, I already implemented this and I also think buffering is a little bit faster, I think limitation here is again checking the buffersize everytime...

Comment: @Ananta, a if statement is just 1 instruction, and the len() is O(1) for a String object.