# Is it better to keep a CSV file open between each run/measurement?

Tags: python, csv

I have a question regarding writing CSV files. I have an instrument where I am going to read a value each minute, then write the value to a CSV file together with a timestamp.

I have written a simple code that works, which is shown as **Code #1** below. But my friend came up with a question: "Why are you opening and closing the file for each run." I couldn't answer his question since I'm a newbie when it comes to both programming and Python.

Nevertheless, I tried to rewrite the code, as shown in **Code #2** below, and then asked my friend whether that was better, but he couldn't answer me.

I hope you could help me out, what is the difference between #1 and #2? Both give the same result when it comes to reading the file afterward.

Is it right that #1 will open and close the file for each run in the while loop, and #2 will keep the file open and close it after the last run?

This is just a simple example. In reality, I am going to expand the code so it will do a measurement every minute, run for 3-4 days and I am going to log multiple voltages and up to 8 temperatures. So, in the end, the file can become quite large, and opening and closing the file can become a bit resource-consuming.

#### Code #1:

```
import csv
import datetime
import time

no_meas = 5 #number of measurements
cur_meas = 1    # current measurement number


while cur_meas <= no_meas:
    cur_time = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%H:%M:%S')
    with open('test.csv', 'a', newline='') as fp:
        a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
        data = [[cur_time, 'test-text']]
        a.writerows(data)
    cur_meas += 1
    time.sleep(60)
```

#### Code #2

```
import csv
import datetime
import time

no_meas = 5 #number of measurements
cur_meas = 1    # current measurement number

with open('test.csv', 'a', newline='') as fp:
    while cur_meas <= no_of_meas:
        cur_time = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%H:%M:%S')
        a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=csv_delimiter)
        data = [[cur_time, 'test-text']]
        a.writerows(data)
        cur_meas += 1
        time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: Better ask this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think you should try to avoid open-close operations to the minimum as possible since the write-read is less expensive, with that said it really depends on the file size, amount of operations and so on, what you can also do it to time your runs with each code.

Comment: @Lutz Horn. OK, I will remember that. i didn't know that codereview existed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it better to open/close a file every time vs keeping it open until the process is finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349020/is-it-better-to-open-close-a-file-every-time-vs-keeping-it-open-until-the-proces)

Answer (score 0):

If the the frequency of your writes to the file is high you may want to avoid the open/close overhead. Nevertheless, from what you describe it doesn't seem like an issue (1 open/close per minute for writing a couple of dozens of measurements). Even after a few days your file should not exceed the 1-3MB size.

Since you're planning to let it run for a few days, you should handle a scenario of failure without losing the gathered data. In the first case you won't lose any data. In the second case, I'd recommend adding a flush after each write to make sure the data is written to disk:

```
a.writerows(data)
fp.flush()
os.fsync(fp.fileno())
```

Comment: when using flush i think it's recommended to add `os.fsync()`, just to be sure there is a full disk write :)

Comment: @KobiK, yeah, that would full proof the solution against system failure. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @OernD, very good suggestion to add flush. I have added the lines you have written but I get an error message:

AttributeError: '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'flush'

Comment: @ThomasGundersen, sorry about that. flush() should be called on the opened file rather than the csv writer. Fixed the answer.

Comment: @OernD, it worked, but I got an error on os.fsync() and number of arguments. I tried fp as argument in fsync(), is that correct?

Comment: @ThomasGundersen, fsync() requires a file descriptor. I updated the answer to show how it's done.

Comment: @OernD and everyone else. OK. This is a bit like magic for me. I don't get any error messages, but I can't really say I understand the underlying logic of os.fsync(fp.fileno()). Escpecially the use of fp.fileno() as an argument.
Are you any one able to explain in simple words what os.fsync(fp.fileno()) and fp.fileno() does?

I have found this page, but I'm still a bit confused:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_fsync.htm

Comment: @ThomasGundersen, I'll take a stab at it. Generally, there are 2 levels of buffers when writing to a file in Python: 1. python level buffer 2. OS level buffer. When you write() in python, the data will be kept in a buffer of a certain size (configurable using the open command). According to a certain criteria the buffer is written to the file from time to time. When this happens, the OS may also have a buffer and only when that buffer is full would the data get written to stable storage. So flush() empties the python buffer and fsync() empties the OS buffer.