# How to make python write on a file live

Tags: python, loops

Hello my question is simple, I have a loop that write results on a file and it takes time to go through the whole loop, is there a way I can make python write every result it gets, or do I have to close the file inside the loop ? will it be longer ? 
thank you guys

```
fi= open('results','a') 
for j in range(1,100):
    tt=j
    res=scipy.optimize.newton(zero,15)
    fi.write("\n"+str(tt)+", " + str(res)+", "+str( zero(res) ) )
print("done")
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
winsound.Beep(300,2000)
fi.closed
```

Comment: plz show your work before we help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python file open/close everytime vs keeping it open until the process is finished](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11349020/1165509)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to write using the flush() function.

```
outputFile.flush()
```

More informations on the flush() function on this link: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print

That's nearly the same request than this one: [Python 2.7 : Write to file instantly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984092/python-2-7-write-to-file-instantly)