# Python : Efficiency of a program reading from an 8 million lines file and store into separate files

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, file

What my program does is that it takes the first word and second word of a line and place it into a csv file with the initial of the first word

> Ex: "Learn Python" would be placed in "l_words.csv" and it would
>   append [Learn, Python] into the file.

Problem is the data I am reading from an 8 million lines long file. I ran it for 6 hours and it only finish 2.5% [I wrote codes to update me on the progress.] Is the function "add_to_file(a,fw,sw)" inefficient? If so, how can I improve it?

```
def add_to_file(a,fw,sw): #Function to add to file

    file = open(a.lower()+'_words.csv', 'a+') #Create or open file

    file.write(fw + ',' + sw + '\n') #write to file



Data = open('data.txt', 'r') # Read data

for line in Data: #loop every line in file

    for i in line: #loop every character in line

        ### insert code that get 1st word and 2nd put into file with the add_to_file, then get 2nd and 3rd then 3rd and 4th and so on.

        add_to_file(f_char, first_word, second_word)
```

I tried my best to make the code in `###` efficient. There is no loops within that line.

I think the `for line in Data` and `for i in line` is necessary and not possible to improve it?

Edit: Thanks to that 1 comment I figured it out.
new code :

```
def add_to_file(a,f_w,s_w):   #Function to add to file
    if a == 'a':
        fa.write(f_w + ',' + s_w + '\n')    #write to file
    elif a == 'b':
        fb.write(f_w + ',' + s_w + '\n')
    elif a == 'c':
        fc.write(f_w + ',' + s_w + '\n')
    elif a == 'd':
        fd.write(f_w + ',' + s_w + '\n')
    elif a == 'e':
        fe.write(f_w + ',' + s_w + '\n')
    elif a == 'f':
        ff.write(f_w + ',' + s_w + '\n')
    elif a == 'g':
        fg.write(f_w + ',' + s_w + '\n')
    elif a == 'h':
        fh.write(f_w + ',' + s_w + '\n')
    elif a == 'i':
        fi.write(f_w + ',' + s_w + '\n')
    elif a == 'j':
        fj.write(f_w + ',' + s_w + '\n')
    elif a == 'k':
        fk.write(f_w + ',' + s_w + '\n')
    elif a == 'l':
        fl.write(f_w + ',' + s_w + '\n')
    elif a == 'm':
        fm.write(f_w + ',' + s_w + '\n')
    elif a == 'n':
        fn.write(f_w + ',' + s_w + '\n')
    elif a == 'o':
        fo.write(f_w + ',' + s_w + '\n')
    elif a == 'p':
        fp.write(f_w + ',' + s_w + '\n')
    elif a == 'q':
        fq.write(f_w + ',' + s_w + '\n')
    elif a == 'r':
        fr.write(f_w + ',' + s_w + '\n')
    elif a == 's':
        fs.write(f_w + ',' + s_w + '\n')
    elif a == 't':
        ft.write(f_w + ',' + s_w + '\n')
    elif a == 'u':
        fu.write(f_w + ',' + s_w + '\n')
    elif a == 'v':
        fv.write(f_w + ',' + s_w + '\n')
    elif a == 'w':
        fw.write(f_w + ',' + s_w + '\n')
    elif a == 'x':
        fx.write(f_w + ',' + s_w + '\n')
    elif a == 'y':
        fy.write(f_w + ',' + s_w + '\n')
    elif a == 'z':
        fz.write(f_w + ',' + s_w + '\n')

fa = open('a_words.csv', 'a+')
fb = open('b_words.csv', 'a+')
fc = open('c_words.csv', 'a+')
fd = open('d_words.csv', 'a+')
fe = open('e_words.csv', 'a+')
ff = open('f_words.csv', 'a+')
fg = open('g_words.csv', 'a+')
fh = open('h_words.csv', 'a+')
fi = open('i_words.csv', 'a+')
fj = open('j_words.csv', 'a+')
fk = open('k_words.csv', 'a+')
fl = open('l_words.csv', 'a+')
fm = open('m_words.csv', 'a+')
fn = open('n_words.csv', 'a+')
fo = open('o_words.csv', 'a+')
fp = open('p_words.csv', 'a+')
fq = open('q_words.csv', 'a+')
fr = open('r_words.csv', 'a+')
fs = open('s_words.csv', 'a+')
ft = open('t_words.csv', 'a+')
fu = open('u_words.csv', 'a+')
fv = open('v_words.csv', 'a+')
fw = open('w_words.csv', 'a+')
fx = open('x_words.csv', 'a+')
fy = open('y_words.csv', 'a+')
fz = open('z_words.csv', 'a+')

Data = open('data.txt', 'r') # Read data
    for line in Data: #loop every line in file
        for i in line: #loop every character in line
            ### insert code that get 1st word and 2nd put into file with the add_to_file, then get 2nd and 3rd then 3rd and 4th and so on.
        add_to_file(f_char, first_word, second_word)

fa.close()
fb.close()
fc.close()
fd.close()
fe.close()
ff.close()
fg.close()
fh.close()
fi.close()
fj.close()
fk.close()
fl.close()
fm.close()
fn.close()
fo.close()
fp.close()
fq.close()
fr.close()
fs.close()
ft.close()
fu.close()
fv.close()
fw.close()
fx.close()
fy.close()
fz.close()
```

Comment: File open operations are costly.   You're opening a file ever time you encounter a character.   Instead, cache the file handle and re-use it.  
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11349501/1018580

Answer (score 1):

a more "pythonic" way to do this is with a dict of file descriptors:

```
import string
file = {char: open(char+'_words.csv') for char in string.ascii_lowercase}
```

then you can access each file by the char:

```
file[char].write(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your new code is horrible, not sorry to say. If you ever find yourself repeating yourself, find a different way.

I'm sure even my code can be improved upon, but use it as an example.

```
import string

def add_to_file(a,f_w,s_w):
    files[a].write(f_w + ',' + s_w + '\n')

files = {}
for letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
     files[letter] = open(f"{letter}_words.csv", "a+")

Data = open('data.txt', 'r') # Read data
    for line in Data: #loop every line in file
        for i in line: #loop every character in line
            ### insert code that get 1st word and 2nd put into file with the add_to_file, then get 2nd and 3rd then 3rd and 4th and so on.
        add_to_file(f_char, first_word, second_word)

for file in files.items():
    file[1].close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides constantly reopening files, you have a lot to improve here.
The most efficient way to do this is the following:

1.

(important) Load whole input file into memory, then split it to lines, then iterate over those lines. Python is extremely good at buffering, but still, you are here torturing your disk/SSD, (by doing for line in opened_file_for_reading) and it is never done so for big files. OK, better said, you are making your OS torture your storage device. :D
So you should do:

```
f = open("inputfile")
content = f.read()
f.close()
# You can have enough RAM to put few GB into a variable. if you need to
# Then you do:
content = content.splitlines()
# Then:
for line in content:
    (...)
```

2.

After splitting the content into a list of lines, you can do the following (or something similar) first to classify them for your output

```
classified = {}
add = classify.setdefault
for line in content:
    line = line.strip()
    if not line: continue
    if not line[0].isalnum(): continue
    add(line[0], []).append(line)
# Now you populated dictionary 'classified' with first
# character of each line that contains text (where first char is letter or digit) as a key, and all such lines stored in a value as a list
```

3.

Save them to files with no processing, just an example:

```
# Open all files first (better if you want further optimization later
# otherwise, you may open each per iteration over classified, now it wouldn't matter
files = {}
for key in classified:
    files[key] = open(key+".txt", "w")
# Save all lines per file:
for key, f in files.items():
    lines = "\n".join(classified[key])
    f.write(lines)
# Then close all files:
for f in files.values():
    f.close()
```

4.

I separated openning, writing and closing into 3 different loops because you can also do more optimization.
For most system calls (all IO operations) the Python GIL is released. That means that you can split classified in groups, of, say, 8 keys, and run writting in len(classified)/8 threads.
In this way you would be parallely writing to your storage device, and the OS will do its best to optimize the process. This works nice, and is pretty optimized, although it can be done more with some other crazy techniques, but you do not need more, as you are not dealing with binary content. If you can avoid nested loops, do so. It is better here to abuse a bit the RAM than wait for hours to be done. Also, avoid branching like you did with elifs, this is also costing you speed.