# Python: re-open file on each iteration or truncate to overwrite?

Tags: python, performance, resources, overwrite

In Python, if you have a loop, in each iteration of which you want to write to a file (pickling in my case), overwriting whatever data is already there, one option is to open the file before the loop, keep it open, and truncate it on each iteration to erase the previous data before writing new data:

```
import pickle
with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
    for blah in blahs:
        file.truncate(0)
        file.seek(0)
        pickle.dump(blah, file)
```

and another is to just re-open the file on each iteration, as opening it in `wb` automatically truncates it:

```
import pickle
for blah in blahs:
    with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
        pickle.dump(blah, file)
```

Which is best (in terms of performance/speed and handling system resources etc)? Is there a better way to overwrite data in an already-open file than using `file.truncate()` and `file.seek()` as above?

I'm aware a similar question has been asked ([Is it better to open/close a file every time vs keeping it open until the process is finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349020/is-it-better-to-open-close-a-file-every-time-vs-keeping-it-open-until-the-proces)) but there it appears to be about when you want to append on each iteration rather than overwrite, so I'm wondering if the process of truncating etc in the latter results in any significance performance degradation that would tip the scales?

Comment: `Which is best (in terms of performance` - sounds like you could easily time both approaches in your specific setting.

Comment: @FlyingTeller The question is more to know whether there are general system-independent concepts that would render one better than the other (and what those concepts are), based on things beyond just performance (resource handling etc), and any other general wisdom and tips relevant to this

Comment: I really don't understand why you want to use a loop if you keep overwriting the data. You could simply write the last entry in `blahs`.

Comment: @Matthias The code given is merely an illustrative example of the basic structure - it's obviously not meant for use in practice. A example of a practical use-case for the structure is a while loop with data being dynamically generated, and you want to write the data in each iteration to a file as a backup before processing it further in the loop, then after you've processed it you no longer need the backup, hence it can be subsequently overwritten.

Comment: On many platforms, `truncate(0)` does zero filling. You can confirm this by doing `truncate(0)` and then writing 1 byte without `seek(0)`. So doing `seek`, `dump`, then `truncate` (if necessary) in that order will reduce the amount of redundant zero filling. However, the difference is far less than the time it takes to `dump`, so I don't think it's worth doing. Another possibility is that if the buffer size is sufficiently larger than `blah`, it might be able to reduce the number of actual writes to disk. This exploit would not be possible for re-open, since it always writes on closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like guessing so I profiled the two approaches:

```
import pickle
import tempfile
from random import choices
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, digits
from pathlib import Path

from performance_measurement import run_performance_comparison


class Bla:
    def __init__(self):
        population = ascii_uppercase + digits + ascii_lowercase
        self._content = str.join("", choices(population, k=50))


def truncate_approach(blahs: list[Bla], filename: str):
    with open(filename, "wb") as file:
        for blah in blahs:
            file.truncate(0)
            file.seek(0)
            pickle.dump(blah, file)


def reopen_approach(blahs: list[Bla], filename: str):
    for blah in blahs:
        with open(filename, "wb") as file:
            pickle.dump(blah, file)


def setup(N):
    return [[Bla() for i in range(N)], Path(tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile().name)]


run_performance_comparison(
    approaches=[truncate_approach, reopen_approach],
    data_size=[10, 20, 30, 100, 200, 300, 1000, 2000, 3000],
    setup=setup,
    number_of_repetitions=10,
)
```

`truncate_approach` is slightly faster. I assume it's because we interact with the disk less and sometimes get to truncate the content and re-set the writebuffer before we have to interact with the hard disc.

[image]

Profiling code:

```
import timeit
from functools import partial

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from typing import List, Dict, Callable

from contextlib import contextmanager
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np


@contextmanager
def data_provider(data_size, setup=lambda N: N, teardown=lambda: None):
    data = setup(data_size)
    yield data
    teardown(*data)


def run_performance_comparison(approaches: List[Callable],
                               data_size: List[int],
                               *,
                               setup=lambda N: [N],
                               teardown=lambda *N: None,
                               number_of_repetitions=5,
                               title='Performance Comparison',
                               data_name='N',
                               yscale='log',
                               xscale='log'):
    approach_times: Dict[Callable, List[float]] = {approach: [] for approach in approaches}
    for N in data_size:
        with data_provider(N, setup, teardown) as data:
            print(f'Running performance comparison for {data_name}={N}')
            for approach in approaches:
                function = partial(approach, *data)
                approach_time = min(timeit.Timer(function).repeat(repeat=number_of_repetitions, number=1))
                approach_times[approach].append(approach_time)

    for approach in approaches:
        plt.plot(data_size, approach_times[approach], label=approach.__name__)
    plt.yscale(yscale)
    plt.xscale(xscale)

    plt.xlabel(data_name)
    plt.ylabel('Execution Time (seconds)')
    plt.title(title)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```